# Do I just have to include the ui.router module just once or in each module I set up?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
var app = angular
    .module('app', ['ui.router', 'admin', 'home', 'questions', 'ui.compat', 'ngResource', 'LocalStorageModule'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
```

Then in the modules like 'admin' I have:

```
angular
    .module('admin', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

    }])
```

Rather than doing this in two files for example would it also be better to chain everything into the one file? Also do I need to set up my include of 'ui.router' in the admin module if it's already in the main module?

Can someone tell me if this is the correct way for me to set up my modules.

Comment: I don't see any problem with you approach. Regarding declaring the dependency on `ui.router` twice, you can always try and see what works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AngularJS App](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/tree/master/client/src/app) can give you a reference. I think that approach is correct, but as you probably figured it out, you don't need to include the dependency twice.

In your example, you can freely remove `ui.router` as `admin` already has it. If you leave it like that and you ever want to even change the name of the `ui.router`, you need to go through all files that have it (in your case two files instead of one. It's no fun when you have a hundred). Leaving it the way it is atm, however, is harmless (as far as I know), and it might even be more readable for your team.